# Why Java Logarithm and answer using calculator not equal

Tags: java

I am new to Java, sorry I have this wield question came up, I tried to do `log(0.5)` in Java using `Math.log(0.5)`, I did `log(0.5`) in calculator and answer is `-0.3` and I computed `Math.log(0.5)`, answer is `-0.69`. Any one know where I did it wrong?

Comment: You need to use the right logarithm-function. See here in the tutorial.
https://www.baeldung.com/java-logarithms

Comment: Log base 10 (0.5)= -0.30102999566.  Log base e (0.5) = -0.69314718055995.  "Log to the base e" (ln x) is the [Natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm).  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) for Math.log() clearly says: "log(double a)
Returns the natural logarithm (base e) of a double value."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Math.log` calculates a "natural logarithm", that is, base e.  On your calculator, this might be denoted by a button `ln` or similar.

To get a "common logarithm", that is, base 10, you need `Math.log10`.  This is the function represented by the `log` button on your calculator.